# Clock division and duty cycle for ST8034P Smart Card interface

Tags: integrated-circuit, interface, specifications, smart-card

The ST8034 is a family of interface ICs for contact Smart Card. [Here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st8034p.pdf) is the Data Sheet. My question is about the ST8034PQR.

- when the CLK output is active, does f<sub>CLK</sub> = f<sub>CLKIN</sub> or f<sub>CLK</sub> = f<sub>CLKIN</sub>/2 ?
- assuming  f<sub>CLK</sub> = f<sub>CLKIN</sub> : is there some duty cycle (or other characteristic) to be met on the CLKIN input in order to get the specified 45/55% duty cycle on the CLK output?

---

Context is migrating a design from ST8034ATDT to ST8034PQR. The old design uses the f<sub>XTAL</sub>/2 functionality of table 13, with CLKDIV = 1. The ST8034P has no CLKDIV input. But it's untold in the Data Sheet if the behavior is that of CLKDIV = 1 or CLKDIV = 0.

A clue that f<sub>CLK</sub> = f<sub>CLKIN</sub> is that both have the same maximum frequency (26 MHz). But then, I wonder how the 45/55% duty cycle for CLK in table 8 is obtained without some slightly tighter duty cycle spec on CLKIN.